# SSRS error bar chart with column chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report which creates the following chart:
[image]

I want the line bars (Range Error bar) chart series to be separate under the correct column.
How can i do it?

Comment: Are you using **StripLines**? You would use the **IntervalOffset** property. If your line is supposed to go over the **Blue** bar, I think it would be **-.5**.

Comment: OK. But the categories are dynamic. there might be more columns . so i want the correct line to be under the correct column

Answer (score 0):

Select the series, in the properties window, go to Custom attributes and change the DrawSideBySide property to True